# Rewrite Conditions Backreferences passed to all rules?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, http, rewrite, url

Is there a way to get back references for Rewrite Conditions to be passed to all subsequent rewrite rules?

Here's an example:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (bob).localhost [NC]    
RewriteRule ^/where/? /index.php\?user_name=%1
RewriteRule ^/who/? /index.php\?user_name=%1
```

In this example I would expect this behavior:

```
http://bob.localhost/where => http://bob.localhost/where/index.php?user_name=bob
http://bob.localhost/who   => http://bob.localhost/who/index.php?usern_ame=bob
```

But for the second rule I receive *http://bob.localhost/who/index.php?user_name=* instead.

I've tried this on several different distro's using Apache 2.2.17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditions only apply to the very next rule.  You'll need to repeat the condition in order for it to apply to another rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (bob).localhost [NC]    
RewriteRule ^/where/? /index.php\?user_name=%1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (bob).localhost [NC]    
RewriteRule ^/who/? /index.php\?user_name=%1
```

In your example, if your request's HTTP_HOST value *doesn't* match `(bob).localhost`, your request will skip the `^/where/?` rule (even if it matches), but can use the `^/who/?` rule.

Answer (score 3):

As DerfK indicates, rewritecond is for only one rewrite rule.

You might consider an alternate strategem however, setting and reading environment variables.

```
# this grabby rewrite will match anything, 
# *and* set 'bob' in a custom rewrite environment variable 
# it uses 'next' with the 'no sub requests' caveat to avoid loops 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (bob).localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=host_uname:%1] [N,NS]

# All these rules should then be evaluated, 
# in the 'next' pass - with the 'host_uname' env variable available   
RewriteRule ^/where/? /index.php\?user_name=%{ENV:host_uname}
RewriteRule ^/who/? /index.php\?user_name=%{ENV:host_uname}
```

Comment: Aha, I did try that and couldn't it to work. Although your example is different than what I tried. I'll have to try it also. Thank you.